# Не работает sm в Bootstrap 4

Tags: css, css3, bootstrap, bootstrap4

Подскажите почему не включаеться класс sm, если к примеру убрать md класс то sm работает.
http://prntscr.com/jy2427 вот скрин проблемы, ширина экрана стоит 500px, но md не хочет отключаться

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">   
  <div class="img-block col-sm-12 col-md-7 col-lg-7">
    <img src="phone.png">
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

P.S Подключал версию 3.3.7 все работало нормально

Comment: Может картинка раздвигает контейнер? Проверьте ширину родительских элементов. И было бы круто, если бы вы привели наглядный страницы yна какомнибудь https://plnkr.co/

Comment: Вместо картинки ставил текст, аналогично.
Если убираю md то sm работает
<div class="img-block col-sm-12 col-lg-7">
    <img src="phone.png">
  </div>

Comment: У img-block какие-нибудь стили заданы?

Comment: padding-top: 40px;

Comment: Бутстрап почему то считает что ширина подходит под md. Проверьте ширину body. возможно чтото гдето его раздвигает.

Comment: Кроме бутстрап больше стилей нет, для body используеться их _reboot.scss

Comment: А вы не с телефона смотрите?

Comment: Что с телефона что с компютера результат один и тот же